# How can I set jquery ui Dialog minwidth but have it grow larger if possible?

Tags: css, layout, dynamic, width, jquery-ui-dialog

I want to have my jquery UI dialog at minimum 1000px width but if a person has a wide monitor then I would like it to be as wide as It can (something like window.innerWidth - 100)

Is this possible with jquery ui dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just use the width option. See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbeAF/2/).

```
$("#dialog").dialog({width: function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1000) {
        // Wide.
        return $(window).width() - 100;
    }
    // Not wide.
    return 1000;
}});
```

Comment: can i set this width property on initialization or do i need to do this after?

Comment: @leora By doing it the way I posted, the width is set every time the dialog initializes. If you want it set on page initialization, just use a fixed number such as `$("#dialog").dialog({width: 1000});`.